# Kalman Filter with uncertainty on time of acquisition of the observables

Tags: kalman-filter

I have already developed a function Kalman Filter (KF) for my system, but I have a problem: I have un uncertainty on the time of acquisition of the observation. My sensor data might look like this:

```
t(s)  data
0     12.3
15    42.1
30    56.5
34    59.6
45    40.5
```

The time in fact does not have decimals, therefore the time 30s could be 30.000 just as well as 30.999.

You might ask how is it possible that I do not have the correct time, since the KF is a real-time algorithm: it's a long story, just trust that I have to use a KF. Batch filters will not do for my requirements. In the future, where this KF will be implemented, I will have a precise timestamp, but for now this is what I have and I need to make it work.

The fact is that the 1 second uncertainty is not critical most times: the dynamics is very slow, therefore if the observation is sampled every 15s, the KF will filter out the time uncertainty. The problem is when extra observations come around: two observations might be tagged at 45 and 46 seconds, but might have happened at 45.9 and 46.0, stretching a 100ms interval to 1 second.

Easiest solution for now is to drop observations that are too close to each other, but I was wondering if any of you could point me towards a neater, mathematical solution that could account for this uncertainty.
I have read a lot of literature on KF but all of them assume the acquisition time is perfect and never question it. Maybe it is just not possible with the KF?

One thing that I tried is for every step, integrating the state between *.000 and *.999 and picking the one that deviates the least from the observation, but this ended up diverging very often.

Comment: You could maybe interpret it as measuring at *.5 and consider the position uncertainty to be 0.5 times the velocity.